# Remove an item from a custom list

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<Fill> items`

Here is the `Fill` class :

```
public class Fill
{
    public string arret { get; set;}
    public string ligneSens { get; set;}
}
```

How can I remove an item from this List using the string value `arret` and `ligneSens` ?

Example :

```
void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e, string arretName, string ligneSensName)
{
    var aFill = new Fill
    {
        arret = arretName,
        ligneSens = ligneSensName
    };

    items.Remove(aFill); //<--- this doesn't work
}
```

Sorry for the title of the post I didn't know how to ask that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of `object`. When you call the `Remove` on a reference type (classes) then it will look for one by it's `Equals` method.

```
public class Fill
{
    public string arret { get; set; }
    public string ligneSens { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Fill;
        if(other == null)
            return false;

        return other.arret == arret && other.ligneSens == ligneSens;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return arret.GetHashCode() ^
               ligneSens.GetHashcode();
    }
}
```

*For what are the best practices on `GetHashCode()` overriding search online, there are many questions about it*

Another way, is to specifically say what to [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) by passing a predicate to evaluate for each item in the collection:

```
items.RemoveAll(item => item.arret = arretName &&  
                        item.ligneSens == ligneSensName);
```

Comment: What do I have to Implement I dont' know Equals and GetHashCode ? Have you got a more develop code ?

Comment: yes, another option is to define equality for ``Fill``

Answer (score 4):

You have to  use `RemoveAll()` for that, currently you are passing a newly created object, about which `items` does not have information, because it is a new reference not the same reference :

```
void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e, string arretName, string ligneSensName)
{
   items.RemoveAll(item => item.arret == arretName &&  item.ligneSens == ligneSensName);
}
```

Comment: edit the assignment hehe

Comment: Thanks for pointing @Sherlock corrected

Answer (score 2):

Use List API [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

`items.RemoveAll(x => x.arret.Equals("value") && x.ligneSensName.Equals("ligneValue"));`

Comment: Just to be precise: `RemoveAll` has nothing to do with LINQ, it's an instance method of `List<T>`. LINQ has a functional approach and does not change existing collections or their elements.

Comment: @RenéVogt thanks for pointing it out, I'm used to term api's using lamba expression as LINQ